# Prevent automatic popToRootViewController on double-tap of UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

The default behavior of a UITabBarController is to pop the contained UINavigationController to the root view controller when a particular tab is tapped a second time. I have a particular use case where I'm wanting this to not work automatically, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to prevent this.

Has anyone run into this, and if so, what did you do? Do I need to subclass UINavigationController and override popToRootViewController or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the [tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:) method of the [UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/).

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    return viewController != tabBarController.selectedViewController;
}
```

Don't forget to set the delegate of the tab bar controller to the object that actually implements this delegate method.

Comment: Brilliant. I don't know how I missed that in the delegate protocol. It worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

this is what I did:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
{

    if ([[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:[tabBarController selectedIndex]] == viewController)

            return NO;

    return YES;

}
```

regards

Answer (score 5):

**Update Swift 4.1**

> Stop Double Tap for all tabs.

```
extension TabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    //for blocking double tap on all tabs.
    return viewController != tabBarController.selectedViewController
}}
```

> Stop Double Tap on only one specific tab. Here it's for 3rd Tab.

```
extension TabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    //for blocking double tap on 3rd tab only
    let indexOfNewVC = tabBarController.viewControllers?.index(of: viewController)
    return ((indexOfNewVC != 2) ||
        (indexOfNewVC != tabBarController.selectedIndex))       
}}
```

Hope it helps...

Thanks!!!

Comment: Don't forget to set the delegate of the tab bar controller to the object that actually implements this

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is a little strange, but a handy shortcut in case of deep hierarchy!

You can implement following UITabBarControllerDelegate methods to disable this system wide shortcut:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITabBarControllerDelegate

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tbc shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)vc {
    UIViewController *tbSelectedController = tbc.selectedViewController;

    if ([tbSelectedController isEqual:vc]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift 3 version:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    return viewController != tabBarController.selectedViewController
}
```