# How to stop tab bar's second tap which pops to navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, root

I have a tab bar based app. All tabs have a navigation controller as the root.
If the user taps on the tab again if the tab is active, it pops back to the navigation controller.

How can I stop this behavior?

So in fact I have a navigation controller + a hidden `viewcontroller` that makes some decisions + another view controller. Sorry for the misleading information in the original question. I use the hidden `viewcontroller` for all the tabs, 3 of them, since I have the login screen on all 3 if the user is not logged in. If the user logs in, then I pop the login screen, and put the `1,2,3` individual `viewcontrollers` on each tab.

First tap:

```
 0 : class=Crossing: 0x645c8a0>  
 1 : class=FavoritesViewController: 0x64ac140>  
 shouldSelectViewController : UINavigationController  
 UINavigationController topclass:FavoritesViewController  
 myTabBarController.selectedViewController :UINavigationController  
 did disappear  
 didSelectViewController : UINavigationController  
 UINavigationController topclass:FavoritesViewController
```

Second tap:

```
 0 : class=Crossing: 0x645c8a0>  
 1 : class=FavoritesViewController: 0x64ac140>  
 shouldSelectViewController : UINavigationController  
 UINavigationController topclass:FavoritesViewController  
 myTabBarController.selectedViewController :UINavigationController  
 didSelectViewController : UINavigationController  
 UINavigationController topclass:Crossing
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849975/prevent-automatic-poptorootviewcontroller-on-double-tap-of-uitabbarcontroller

Comment: Yes, thanks for the link too. But somehow it does not work in this case. I need to somehow identify which viewcontroller is acted on in the shouldSelect method, so I can do something about it. As the debug log shows, somehow I cannot get my hand on it yet. They look the same.

Answer (score 7):

@MarkGranoff was on the right track for doing this, but the way to do it is by doing something like this:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController] == tabBarController.selectedIndex)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

or in a less verbose way:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    return (viewController != tabBarController.selectedViewController);
}
```

If you only want to block the default behaviour for a certain tab then you can do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger indexOfNewViewController = [tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    // Only the second tab shouldn't pop home 
    return ((indexOfNewViewController != 1) ||
            (indexOfNewViewController != tabBarController.selectedIndex));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3**

1. Subclass your `UITabBarController` and implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate` on that class.

   `class viewMain: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {`
2. In `viewDidLoad`, set your class's delegate to be itself

   `self.delegate = self`
3. Add this function

   `func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
       return (viewController != tabBarController.selectedViewController);
   }`

Answer (score 1):

In your application delegate (which I assume is the delegate for your UITabBarController), try implementing `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` and return NO if the view controller to be selected is not at its root view. This, of course, may backfire for tabs that were switched *away* from when you try to go back to them... Hmm....

Comment: yes, exactly. I tried this, but then you cannot switch tabs.

Comment: You may have to subclass `UITabBarController` so you can implement your own `popToRootViewController:` method that simply does nothing. Worth a shot, I'd say.

Comment: [((UINavigationController*)tbSelectedController) visibleViewController] is another useful method. It works if I have root+1 if I check the 1 class and make sure return NO. But if I have other viewcontrollers on the stack, it will still go back to the root.

Comment: @MarkGranoff UITabBarController doesn't have any popToRootViewController:, that method is implemented by UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the view controller in

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

and you can keep track on the view controllers selected.

Comment: yes, I use that method, but not sure if I can do anything there in this case. I get the viewcontroller or the navigation controller, but not sure what to do so I do not have a pop back. I do not want to see the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

**Update Swift 4.1**

> Stop Double Tap on only one specific tab. Here it's for 3rd Tab.

```
extension TabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    //for blocking double tap on 3rd tab only
    let indexOfNewVC = tabBarController.viewControllers?.index(of: viewController)
    return ((indexOfNewVC != 2) ||
        (indexOfNewVC != tabBarController.selectedIndex))      
}}
```

> Stop Double Tap for all tabs.

```
extension TabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    //for blocking double tap on all tabs.
    return viewController != tabBarController.selectedViewController
}}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Don't forget to set the delegate of the tab bar controller to the object that actually implements this