# click navigation tabbaritem popToRootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

1. first I Install TabBarController directly as a window’s root view controller,and hava a NavigationController in viewControllers.
2. when the app run, I push some new viewcontroller onto the navigation stack
3. **than I tap navigation tabbaritem, the navigationController
   poptoRootViewController**

How can I crash the step 3 event or stop it pop to root?

My solution to stop auto pop to root viewcontroller:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rvc,nil];

tbc.delegate = self;}
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

if([tabBarController selectedViewController] == viewController)
    return NO;
return YES;}
```

if you have an anther solution,wellcome write down.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585899/tab-bar-second-tap-pops-to-navigation-controller-how-to-stop-it

Answer (score 0):

try this code in tab bar app

```
[self.tabBarController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: sorry,i mean to stop the navigationController popToRootViewController when i double click the navigation's tabbarItem .thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

You implement didSelectViewController method in new viewController(push to new viewController)

Import UITabBarControllerDelegate,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
}
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self.tabBarController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: My solution to stop auto pop to root viewcontroller:

    -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rvc,nil];
    
    tbc.delegate = self;}
    -(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

    if([tabBarController selectedViewController] == viewController)
        return NO;
    return YES;}