# Tap twice on selected tab bar item hides the current view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I'm having some issues pushing a view, using the navigation stack.

The problem I encounter is that after touching a tab bar item a view controller is pushed into the navigation stack (from a view controller named FirstViewController) like so :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
}
```

That works as expected, but the actual issue arises when touching the same tab bar item again.

When that happens the current view ( the SecondViewController that was previously pushed) is removed, it's like I would be touching the "done" button.

I can not trace where or why that's happening.

EDIT: This is how I set up the tab bar, view controllers and navigation:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize HomeViewController, FirstViewController, SecondViewController,     ThirdViewController, SettingsViewController, tabBarController, window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]
                                            initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *firstViewControllerNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                      initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];

    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]
                                             initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *secondViewControllerNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                      initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];

    ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc]
                                                  initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *thirdViewControllerNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                      initWithRootViewController:thirdViewController];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[firstViewControllerNav,
                                              secondViewControllerNav];

    UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;

    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

    [self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: this is viewDidLoad of TabBarController ? where is the done button?

Comment: please share your code in touch event of tabBarItem or touch delegate of tabBarContoller wherever your push logic is there for first view controller?

Comment: Hi Kunal, this is the viewDidLoad of FirstViewController an empty UIView Class. (@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController) Also I don't have any code in the touch event, since I'm adding all the controls programmatically in the appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: so is there any code on selecting tab bar item ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Touching a tab bar item twice will cause the navigation controller to pop back to the root view controller. This is expected and built-in behavior.

To prevent this you will have to use the [tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController%3ashouldSelectViewController%3a) method of the [UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/)

I believe something like this will do the trick:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    return viewController != tabBarController.selectedViewController;
}
```

Comment: Ok, is there a way to override this behavior? Should I be implementing this differently?

Comment: I think this behavior is for double tap , thats a different event than doing a single tap on selected one ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in order to apply that code, I should be implementing a custom tab bar controller and adding that delegate right?

Comment: @KunalBalani He mentions that the "issue" occurs when touching the same tab bar item again.

Comment: @GastónAlgaze No, just set the delegate on the UITabBarController and implement the method.

Comment: @trydis, so I should be doing something like this: \\@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

Comment: Then your question is duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585899/tab-bar-second-tap-pops-to-navigation-controller-how-to-stop-it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849975/prevent-automatic-poptorootviewcontroller-on-double-tap-of-uitabbarcontroller

Comment: Thanks @KunalBalani I fixed it by adding the suggested code by trydis, and tabBarController.delegate = self to the appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Sorry if this was a duplicate question it really helped me to understand the topic, i didn't knew the terms that applied to this, for example popToRootViewController, probably this can help others as well.