# Double tap on UITabBarItem doesn't scroll UITableView to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have UITabBarController which each item has NavigationController and each NavigationController has a TableViewController as root view controller.

The problem is tapping on each tab bar item doesn't make table view to scroll to top.

What could be problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you write  [yourtableview setScrollsToTop:YES]; on tapping method of tab bar ?

Comment: @NiravPatel Yes I did!

Comment: In this case, you can set tableview content offset to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer is this:

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    MasterTableViewController * theViewController;
    if (tabBarController.selectedViewController == viewController)
    {
        if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
        {
            UINavigationController * nav = (UINavigationController *)viewController;
            theViewController = (MasterTableViewController *)nav.topViewController;
        }
        else
        {
            theViewController = self;
        }
        if ([theViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(navigationBarDoubleTap:)])
        {
            [theViewController navigationBarDoubleTap:nil];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check if your tab items is [double tapped or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1850951/988169). If yes, then scrollsToTop like below:-

Add below code:-

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [tableView scrollsToTop];
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to scroll to top every time it appears! Only when user double tapped TabBar item.

Comment: When you want it at Top?

Comment: Follow this:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/1850951/988169
Check if your tab item is double tapped or not. If yes, then scrollsToTop

Comment: I did. Please do the needful.