# Tapping selected Tab in UItabbarcontroller working as a popViewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

In my app i am presenting UITabbarcontroller as a modal view controller. There are 3 tabs and i have assigned a UInavigationcontroller to each tab.
Now the problem is if i am tapping an already selected tab, it is working as popViewControllerAnimated function of UInavigationcontroller.

```
UITabBarController *custom = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
custom.delegate = self;
custom.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"footerbar.png"];
[custom setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav, nav1, nav2, nil]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setItemWidth:(self.view.frame.size.width/3)-15];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"yes" forKey:@"loggedIn"];
[self presentViewController:custom animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I am really stuck at the moment.
Need advice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the UITabBarController behaviour, to prevent this please check the link

[Prevent automatic popToRootViewController on double-tap of UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849975/prevent-automatic-poptorootviewcontroller-on-double-tap-of-uitabbarcontroller)